# Set the same seed in random-normal NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I fix the seed in NetLogo for `random-normal` function?

**Explanation:** I use the `random-normal` in setup to initialize `N`turtles their positions.
             Next time also when run setup I wish the `random-normal` to assign these turtles the same                      positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`random-seed`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-seed) is the command that you are looking for.

If you want to play around with random seeds, I would suggest that you read the [**Random numbers** section of the programming guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random) as well. I think you'll find some other useful information there.